# Как передать динамический массив в функцию?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Как передать динамический массив из функции генерации в функцию сортировки?

Пробовал через ссылки, после запроса на выбор алгоритма сортировки - ничего не происходит (*Press any key to continue*):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int genmass2 (int num)
{
int *arr_fsort = new int[num]; // Выделение памяти для массива
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) 
{
// Заполнение массива и вывод значений его элементов
arr_fsort[i]=( rand() % 600 + 0); // диапазон равен от 1 до 600 включительно
cout<<dec<< "Znachenie " << i << " elementa " << arr_fsort[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
int vuborom_sort(int num, int*arr_fsort)
{
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
int min=arr_fsort[i], imin = i;
for (int j=i+1; j<num; j++) {
if(arr_fsort[j]<min) {
min = arr_fsort[j];
imin = j;
}   
}
if (imin != i) {
int t = arr_fsort[i];
arr_fsort[i] = arr_fsort[imin];
arr_fsort[imin] = t;
}       
}
cout << endl;
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
cout <<"Otsortirovannue elementu(metod prostogo vubora): "<<arr_fsort[i]<<endl;
}   
return 0;
}
int main () 
{
int num;
cout<<"Vvedite razmer massiva: "<<endl;
cin>>num;
int count;
cout<<"Vvedite tip generiruemogo massiva 2-obuchnai gen :   ";
cin>>count;
switch (count)
{
case 2:
{
genmass2(num);
break;
}
return 0;
}
cout<<"Vubor tipa sortirovki  2-sortirovka prostum vuborom :  " <<endl;
cin>>count;
switch (count)
{
case 1:
{
int vuborom_sort (int num,int *arr_fsort);
break;
 }
return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ваша функция создания массива

```
int genmass2 (int num)
{
int *arr_fsort = new int[num]; // Выделение памяти для массива
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) 
{
// Заполнение массива и вывод значений его элементов
arr_fsort[i]=( rand() % 600 + 0); // диапазон равен от 1 до 600 включительно
cout<<dec<< "Znachenie " << i << " elementa " << arr_fsort[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
^^^^^^^^^
}
```

возвращает из функции 0. Она нигде не возвращает указатель на созданный массив. Поэтому функция `main` м функция сортировки `vuborom_sort` не имеют доступа к массиву.

Более того вы не вызываете функцию сортировки. В данном фрагменте кода

```
case 1:
{
int vuborom_sort (int num,int *arr_fsort);
break;
 }
```

предложение

```
int vuborom_sort (int num,int *arr_fsort);
```

не является вызовом функция, а является всего лишь локальным объявлением функции.

И я думаю, что в этом предложении

```
arr_fsort[i]=( rand() % 600 + 0); // диапазон равен от 1 до 600 включительно
                             ^^^
```

вы имели в виду 1 вместо 0.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

int * generate_array( size_t n )
{
    const int UPPER_VALUE = 600;

    if ( n == 0 ) return NULL;

    int *a = new int[n]; // Выделение памяти для массива

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        // Заполнение массива и вывод значений его элементов
        a[i] = rand() % UPPER_VALUE + 1; // диапазон равен от 1 до 600 включительно
    } 

    return a;
}

void display_array( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << a[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void selection_sort( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        size_t min = i;
        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) 
        {
            if ( a[j] < a[min] ) min = j;
        }


        if ( min != i ) 
        {
            int t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[min];
            a[min] = t;
        }       
    }
}   

int main() 
{
    size_t n;

    std::cout << "Enter array size: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        int *a = NULL;

        enum generating_type { NONE_GENERATING = 0, NORMAL_GENERATING = 2 };

        int type;

        std::cout << "\nVvedite tip generiruemogo massiva: " 
                << NORMAL_GENERATING << " - obuchnai gen :  ";
        std::cin >> type;

        switch ( type )
        {
            case NORMAL_GENERATING:
                a = generate_array( n );
                break;
            default:
                type = NONE_GENERATING;
                break;
        }

        if ( type == NONE_GENERATING ) return 0; 

        display_array( a, n );

        enum sorting_type { NONE_SORT = 0, SELECTION_SORT = 2 };

        std::cout << "\nVubor tipa sortirovki "
                << SELECTION_SORT << " - sortirovka prostum vuborom :  ";
        std::cin >> type;

        switch ( type )
        {
            case SELECTION_SORT:
                selection_sort( a, n );
                break;
            default:
                type = NONE_SORT;
                break;
        }            

        display_array( a, n );

        delete [] a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может быть следующим:

```
Enter array size: 10

Vvedite tip generiruemogo massiva: 2 - obuchnai gen : 2
441 496 18 529 193 15 296 178 478 203

Vubor tipa sortirovki 2 - sortirovka prostum vuborom : 2
15 18 178 193 203 296 441 478 496 529
```

И лучше писать латинскими буквами английские фразы, а не русские. В противном случае это затрудняет чтение программы.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Массив надо объявить в функции `main`, а то он у Вас за пределами `genmass2` не сможет быть доступен. И добавить его в параметры `genmass2`. Ну и не забывайте удалять динамические массивы. Золотое правило: количество `new` в коде должно быть равно количеству `delete`.
Еще обратите внимание на строки, помеченные `//!!!`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int genmass2 (int num, int*arr_fsort)
{
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) 
{
// Заполнение массива и вывод значений его элементов
arr_fsort[i]=( rand() % 600 + 0); // диапазон равен от 1 до 600 включительно
cout<<dec<< "Znachenie " << i << " elementa " << arr_fsort[i] << endl;
}

return 0;
}
int vuborom_sort(int num, int*arr_fsort)
{
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
int min=arr_fsort[i], imin = i;
for (int j=i+1; j<num; j++) {
if(arr_fsort[j]<min) {
min = arr_fsort[j];
imin = j;
}   
}
if (imin != i) {
int t = arr_fsort[i];
arr_fsort[i] = arr_fsort[imin];
arr_fsort[imin] = t;
}       
}
cout << endl;
for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
cout <<"Otsortirovannue elementu(metod prostogo vubora): "<<arr_fsort[i]<<endl;
}   
return 0;
}
int main () 
{
int num;
cout<<"Vvedite razmer massiva: "<<endl;
cin>>num;
int *arr_fsort = new int[num]; // Выделение памяти для массива      //!!!
int count;
cout<<"Vvedite tip generiruemogo massiva 2-obuchnai gen :   ";
cin>>count;
switch (count)
{
case 2:
{
genmass2(num,arr_fsort);                        //!!!
break;
}
return 0;
}
cout<<"Vubor tipa sortirovki  2-sortirovka prostum vuborom :  " <<endl;
cin>>count;
switch (count)
{
case 1:
{
vuborom_sort (num,arr_fsort);                   //!!!
break;
 }
return 0;
}
}
```

**UPD:** 
Пример:

```
float Max(float *mas, int size)
{
    float max = mas[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (max < mas[i])
            max = mas[i];
    }
    return max;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    float *MyMas = new float [n];
    float maximum = Max(MyMas,n);
    cout << maximum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это не дало никаких результатов все равно не работает

Comment: Не работает как? Ошибка? Отсутствие результатов на экране?

Comment: Тоже Press any key to continue

Comment: Могли бы вы объяснить как правильно передать массив в функцию , как организовать ссылку верно

Comment: Обновил ответ и добавил пример.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку реально помогло